# Sending arp via shell

Tags: bash, networking, arp

Is there a way a send custom (and event undemanded) arp responses via shell (e.g. by hand or by a shell script) on MacOS X or any other UNIX?
In addition, is there a way of making the software ask for the MAC representation for all IPs in the current subnet without sending pings the anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [packet generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packet_generator) might do the trick. The wikipedia page links to some implementations but I don't know if they work on OSX.

Answer (score 4):

Yes there is. This kind of activity is used in ARP Spoofing and ARP Poisoning attacks and is preformed for ex. by `arpspoof`. If You want to discover host's MAC, when You know its IP and it is located in Yours broadcast domain (LAN), use `arping`. ARP is layer 2 protocol, so it's packets are not forwarded by routers but it's much more reliable then ICMP echo (ping).

Some tools:

- `arp` - standard program (win/unix)
  used to list host's IP-MAC address
  association cache, which contains
  already learnt IPs
- `arping` - unix program which sends ARP
  Request for a given IP and displays
  MAC contained in received ARP Response
- `arpspoof` - a program from dsniff package generating bogus ARP Responses

Answer (score 1):

There are also `arp-scan` using `libpcap`; and `arpdropper` using `libnet`.

To passively (or actively) sniff your network for ARP packets and display the IP and MAC address of the machine that generated the packet you may use a Mac OS X application called [ArpSpyX](http://thebends.org/~allen/arpspyx/).

```
# arpdropper requires http://sourceforge.net/projects/libnet-dev/ to compile
# (libnet & arpdropper successfully compiled on Mac OS X 10.6.8)
curl -LO http://thebends.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/misc/arpdropper.c
gcc -Wall -Wextra -lnet -o arpdropper arpdropper.c

./arpdropper

# Usage: ./arpdropper -i <device> -s <source ip> -d <dest ip>
# For arp replies:
#   ./arpdropper -r -i <device> -s <source ip> -m <source mac> -d <dest ip>

# using nmap
# get a pre-compiled Mac OS X version of nmap at:
# http://nmap.org/download.html#macosx or
# http://www.berndsworld.com/downloads/
nmap -PR -oN nmap-arpscan.txt 192.168.0.0/16
```